# Blank screen at login. Intel intergrated graphics, ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, graphics, login, screen

Whenever I boot ubuntu 12.04 from grub, it takes me to the login screen but the screen is completely blank (no backlight at all). I'm running a 64-bit Compaq Presario CQ45 with Intel Intergrated Graphics (Intel(R) HD).

I can connect the laptop to an external display at see ubuntu fine on the external display, but I can't see ubuntu on my laptop screen unless I change the resolution down a little and then ubuntu appears on my laptop. But this only lasts for about 30 minutes and the screen goes blank again.

Answer (score 0):

fn + [your display for projector, example F3 for leno]

Comment: That does nothing.